# "posts_nav_link ()" in Wordpress is not getting CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Good afternoon, 
I am making a website in Wordpress but I have the following problem: I want the navigation links between pages are not underlined (text-decoration: none), but I've tried several ways and I'm not getting. Can anyone help me?

My HTML:

```
<div class="page_navi">
  <?php posts_nav_link('<span class="span_navi">sep</span>','<span class="span_navi">Página Anterior</span>','<span class="span_navi">Proxima Página</span>') ?></div>
```

My CSS:

```
    .page_navi {
    font-family: CreativZoo Regular, sans-serif;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #136f8c;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .page_navi span {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .span_navi {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .span_navi:hover {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #136f8c;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not targeting the `a` elements. Try this.

```
.page_navi a {
    text-decoration: none;
 }
```